# Is the source code required when using Selenium-RC with Grails?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2

Can anyone help with using [Selenium-RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) + Grails? I have used Selenium with Java but had no problem writing the code and launching the browser. But is the source code of my project required when i need to use Selenium-RC with Grails?

Any links to resources to learn will be very helpful.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Did something happen that suggested to you that using Selenium with grails might require accessing your web application's source code?

Answer (score 2):

Try Geb, it's a groovy wrapper for Selenium:

http://www.gebish.org/

http://grails.org/plugin/geb

Comment: i want to automate scenario so the regression becomes less time consuming. so my biggest question i am facing now is.. can we do blackbox testing using selenium-rc using grails?? or it is only used to do whitebox testing

Comment: You cannot do whitebox testing with Selenium.  Selenium drives a browser to interact with a web page, is has no concept of the code layer behind the website (e.g. PHP, ASP, Ruby, etc).

Comment: @Ardesco, it might however be aware of JavaScript code on browser-side, correct?

Comment: Depends on your definition of aware.  You can add hooks into your JavaScript code that Selenium can use and you can use a JavascriptExecutor to use these hooks.  You can also use a JavaScriptExecutor to run your own JavaScript (Basically exactly what an end user could do with a JavaScript console).